# Highcharts - add points to all series using json

Tags: json, highcharts

I want to create dynamically updated chart of network usage / time. Number of series can change due because I don't know how many network adapters will be in the system at the moment.

I wrote a script which returns data in json format:

```
[{"name":"eth0_upload","data":[[1417981348000,5585.0]]},
{"name":"eth0_download","data":[[1417981348000,4258.0]]},
{"name":"lo_upload","data":[[1417981348000,960.0]]},
{"name":"lo_download","data":[[1417981348000,960.0]]}]
```

how can I add this points to my chart? Can I update series like series.addPoints(jsondata, ...) or is there any way to call serie by id/name (like series[eth0_upload].addPoints(jsondata[0], ...)?

Answer (score 1):

You can get serie by id like [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.get)